# CSS: IE 9 hack for margin-left? \9; has no effect

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I have an element that currently has `margin-left: -110px` of course, this works with my design in all browsers except IE. With IE I need to make it `margin-left: 10px`

Normally, I would do my IE hacks by adding `\9;`, such as:

```
margin-left: 10px\9;
```

but it doesnt seem to work with margins. Does anyone know a way to acheive this? Many thanks!

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="newstab">News</li>
    <li id="offerstab">Offers</li>
    <li id="specialsstab">Specials</li>
  </ul>
</div>

#nav {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: -110px;
margin-left: 10px\9;
    margin-top: 160px;
    writing-mode:tb-rl;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I'd be willing to bet you need different CSS for IE9 because your markup is invalid/broken. IE9 generally shouldn't need hacks like this.

Comment: By the way, it works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/teLRA/ Did you redeclare `margin-left` *after* the hack?

Comment: @WesleyMurch yes techically you are right. My margin-left is actualyy -100px; IE

Comment: Please post the actual HTML and CSS that's not working.

Comment: @WesleyMurch added above

Comment: You didn't add the part with the hack; the most important part...

Comment: @WesleyMurch added above in the css.

Comment: `1)` Works fine for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/25KjA/2/ `2)` It doesn't look like you need the hack, looks the same to me in Chrome and IE9 without it. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it was

```
 writing-mode:tb-rl;
```

IE didnt like.

This site was useful:

http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to, you can use an IE conditional block:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .thing {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: hmm no luck! Its odd...If I go into IE's developer tools and find the element and alter the css it works. Its just ignoring the hacks on the style sheet

Comment: @MeltingDog From what you said it doesn't sound like you actually tried this answer (although admittedly, it's not a direct answer). Either that or you aren't sure what effect you're expecting to see.

Comment: @WesleyMurch yes I did try the answer, and experimented with several similar versions. You are meant to place would have written on the header of the HTML doc, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
.class {
     text-align:right;

     @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

     margin-left: 30px

     }
     margin-left: 90px;
 }
```

You can write the specific css for IE, then overwrite other css for other browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]> <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html>             <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then in your CSS, you would target IE7, IE8 or IE9 like this:

```
   .element {  
        margin-left: 20px;  
    }  

    .ie7 .element {  
        margin-left: 10px;  
    }  

    .ie8 .element {  
        margin-left: 15px;  
    }  
    .ie9 .element {  
        margin-left: 10px;  
    }
```

Now every browser will have a left margin of 20px on the element in question, but IE7, IE8 and  IE0 will have a left margin of 10px, 15px and 10px respectively.

Comment: The `\9` hack already works though, and it's the topic of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using margin-left, when you are also using position:absolute?
You won't ever gain the desired effect of a margin when using position absolute (but that is not the *actual* issue here).

When using position absolute, you should always define the elements default datum point consisting of at least a top/bottom and left/right position - in your case, top:0; left:110px; (this is assuming the absolute positioned element is within a position:relative; parent container).

You are allowing the browsers to assume what you want to display, rather than actually defining and telling the browsers what you want to display - You should be doing this without fail on everything you build in CSS.

In not strictly defining where you want an element to sit using absolute positioning, you are asking for trouble in IE (especially lt IE9).